# I am trying to change how many times a sequence changes direction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that adds to a specific variable when the list of integers change from positive to negative to neutral etc, but I keep getting the output of 8 instead of 7 but cannot find the bug. Please see my code below

```
def changing_direction(elements: list[int]) -> int:
    #to check whether true or false with ones and zeros
    x = 0
    #to store last number to check with new number
    a = 0
    #to subtract last number from new number
    b = 0 
    d = 0
    e = 0
    
    
    for i in elements:
        b = a - i
        if b > 0:
            x = 1
        elif b < 0:
            x = 0
        elif b != 0:
            a = i
            e = x
            break
        
        if x != e:
            d += 1
            

        a = i
        e = x
    
    return d
        
    


print("Example:")
print(changing_direction([6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6]))
```

Comment: Use variable names that make sense. It makes no difference to a computer, but it significantly improves readability and therefore ease of debugging

Comment: Can you also explain how you arrived at 7 as the expected result for that input?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, sorry let me ammend there was in error

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, so it changes, (6-4,1-2,9-7,7-8,8-5,5-9,9-4,2-6).

Comment: @DannyMoham1 there are 8 pairs in that, are you sure that you should be getting 7?

Comment: Your `elif b != 0` is never reached because you test for `if b > 0` and `elif b < 0` before?

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your function significantly by using `zip()` and list comprehension, which makes it return the correct value where the first change is not counted.

```
def changing_direction(elements: list[int]) -> int:
    diffs = (i-j for i,j in zip(elements[:-1], elements[1:]) if i-j!=0)
    return sum(i*j < 0 for i,j in zip(diffs[:-1], diffs[1:]))
```

`zip(somelist[:-1], somelist[1:])` basically returns tuples containing consecutive elements as a generator.

We remove all the 0 elements because they cause problems in the following logic.

The main logic here is that 2 consecutive differences when multiplied together will be negative if the direction changes

`sum` here works to count things because True counts as a 1, and False counts as a 0

finally, you could have this as a 1 line lambda if you knew that lists did not have 2 consecutive items as the same value.

```
changing_direction = lambda seq: sum((i-j)*(j-k)<0 for i,j,k in zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:]))
```

such that

```
changing_direction([6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6])
```

retults in 7

Answer (score 0):

You would need to keep track of the last direction - you can easily ignore all directions if they do not differ -  no need to keep `x`.
You also need to keep track of the amount of changes.

This could be done like this:

```
def changing_direction(elems: list[int]) -> int:
    # can not compare with 0 or 1 elem => 0 changes
    if len(elems) < 2: 
        return 0

    changes = 0
    # helper, returns UP or DOWN or umplicit None based on b-a 
    def ud(a,b):
        if b-a > 0: return "UP"
        if b-a < 0: return "DOWN"
        
    # current start direction
    direction = None
    for idx, e in enumerate(elems):
        try:
            # save old direction, initially None
            ld = direction
            # get new direction, maybe None
            direction = ud(e,elems[idx+1])
            print(direction) # --> comment for less output
            
            # if both are not None and different we have a change in direction
            # if either is None: same values this and last time round
            # 
            if direction is not None and ld is not None and ld != direction:
                changes += 1
            if direction is None and ld is not None:
                direction = ld # restore last direction for next time round
        except IndexError:
            pass # end of list reached
                
    return changes

    print("Example:")
    print(changing_direction([6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 2, 6]))
```

to get:

```
Example:
None
None
DOWN
DOWN
UP
UP
UP
DOWN
UP
DOWN
UP
DOWN
DOWN
UP
7
```

Using proper variable names hopefully makes is easy to understand. If you store the "UP","DOWN" in a list you can also use that to count your changes by simply iterating over it.

For a more compact way to count this, look into list comprehensions.